# How to Repair the Corrupted Data & Make it Readable?

Tags: video, images, windows-10, data, data-recovery

I Corrupted my data by taking out the
SD card (which was Adopted as internal storage)multiple times
without

'**EJECT**'
/ Unmount

Since *adopting SD card as internal storage* **encrypted** the card to be used only inside the same Android device & Card's data wasn't accessible neither in another Device nor inside an
SD *card reader*

So,

Reinserted the SD card in the device ( Nokia 6.1+) on which it was adopted as *Internal storage*

Then, in order to *back up* the **data** (which was not *Readable* even in the Android device in which it was adopted)

**Copied** the *Data*
(30GB- Mainly Media files)

via **MTP** using a *USB Cable* to My **PC**.

Data was **not readable** *in the PC* as well

Now,
I don't know whether the Data is simply just

```
     **Corrupt**

          OR

  *Corrupt + Encrypted*
```

I tried to **repair**/*recover* the
*Data*(mainly images and videos) using Klennet Carver

But after scanning the Drive(containing backed up data) for 25+ hour

Found out that it works best mainly to recover data that gets *fragmented* in HDD or memory card. And data is not fragmented in my case.

Now
I don't have the SD card anymore.
All I have is the *corrupt/damaged*
**data** stored on my *PC*.

So,

Can anyone help me out here first to know whether the *copied data* on my PC is simply just **Corrupt** or it's *encrypted* as well along with being corrupt.

And

How to **Repair** this Data
(30 GB of images and videos)
backed up on my **PC** ??

Any online or Offline tools to *repair* the data and make it **readable** again?

Comment: Maybe PhotoRec can help?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul After reading how it all happened, what do you think about whether my Data is just Corrupt or it's encrypted as well??

Comment: Not sure, you should ask at https://android.stackexchange.com first, then create a question when you have clarity on that. Thanks for your understanding and good luck!

Comment: Note: the question has been posted and answered on Super User: https://superuser.com/q/1766796/356789

Comment: I am the one who has explained to OP that question about photo recovery software belongs to Software Recommendations and **not** to Android Enthusiasts. furthermore a little research would have revealed this user has asked on Android Enthusiasts many times, and it is pretty much clear that these files were copied from phone to PC via usb MTP and therefore not encrypted (android doesn't provide encrypted files via MTP)